# Passing data to controller

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5

I have a table of data, each row displays details for a store - which can have an arbitrary, but unique id - and a store number - also unique and non-sequential - plus other information.

When I select a store number I want to display the details for the store.

```
public class StoreViewModel
{
    public FormatViewModel Formats { get; set; }
    public List<StoreDetailsViewModel> StoreData { get; set; }
}
```

***Formats*** contains data for implementation of MvcCheckBoxList and updates the StoreData when checkboxes updated via a FormMethod.GET.

**Store Model:**

```
public class StoreDetailsViewModel
{
    public int StoreID { get; set; }
    public int StoreNo { get; set; }
    public string StoreFormat { get; set; }
    public string Version { get; set; }

    public int CellNo { get; set; }
    [ForeignKey("CellNo")]
    public virtual Cell Cell { get; set; } 
}
```

**Index** page displays table of Stores:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("Details", "Store", FormMethod.Post))
{
    <table class="table table-condensed table-bordered table-hover table-striped small">
        <tr>
            @*<th class="text-center"></th>*@
            <th class="text-center">No.</th>
            <th class="text-center">Format</th>
            <th class="text-center">CBO Version</th>
            <th class="text-center">Cell</th>
            <th class="text-center"></th>
        </tr>

        @foreach (var item in Model.StoreData)
        {
            <tr>
                <td class="text-center">
                    @Html.Hidden("List_StoreIDs", @item.StoreID)
                    @Html.Hidden("id", @item.StoreID)
                    @item.StoreNo
                </td>
                <td class="text-center">@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.StoreFormat)</td>
                <td class="text-center">@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Version)</td>
                <td class="text-center">@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.CellNo)</td>
                <td>
                    <input type="submit" name="submit" value=@item.StoreNo />
                </td>
            </tr>
        }
    </table>
}
```

What I cannot get to work is passing the StoreID for selected row in list of stores (ActionLink would work easily but I need to also pass back List_StoreIDs).

I expected the @Html.Hidden("id") to work but this is *always 1*.

**Controller**

```
public ActionResult Details(int? id, int[] List_StoreIDs, string submit, string book)
{
    if (id == null)
    {
        return new HttpStatusCodeResult(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest);
    }
    Store store = db.Stores.Find(id);
    if (store == null)
    {
        return HttpNotFound();
    }
 ... do something
}
```

Any suggestions please?

Regards
Craig

Comment: Why do you need List_StoreIDs as well, this seems to be the same as Item.StoreID when rendered in your model.  AS you only use StoreID to retrieve your model, surely this is all that your controller requires?

Comment: @Paddy I need to pass a list of the StoreIDs rendered in Index View to Details Controller.

Comment: Why a submit button?  This will submit your entire form, with multiple Id's present (this is why it is always 1).  An action link might be your best bet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a submit button per row.  Do you want to submit the whole form when one of the submit buttons is clicked, or are you only interested in the details changed in the row that also contains the submit button?

If it's the latter, you could have a form per row, then the "id" value will be correct for each form (you'd probably put the form in a single  element, and format the form using Bootstrap css)

Answer (score 1):

If you make your controller accept `StoreViewModel` and then use `Html.HiddenFor` the data will be available in the controller.

Comment: Hi, if it worked could you accept by clicking the green tick under the arrows next to this answer.

Comment: I made the suggested changes:

Index:
`code`
    @foreach (var item in Model.StoreData)
    {
        using (Html.BeginForm("Details", "Store", FormMethod.Post))
        {
            <tr>
                <td>
                    @Html.HiddenFor(modelItem => item.StoreID, new { id = @item.StoreID } )
                </td>
                <td>
                    <input type="submit" name="submit" value=@item.StoreNo />
                </td>
            </tr>
        }
    }
`code`

Controller:
public ActionResult Details(int? id, StoreViewModel storeVM)

But id storeVM are null.

Answer (score 1):

The problem I see is that you have a hidden field and submit button in each row of the table, but all of the rows are in the same form. So the id passed to the controller will be a list of all the ids in the form (presumably starting with "1") rather than the specific one you clicked on.